# Special Field in JSON Data using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a data structure that has a special property. The data structure represents stock pricing data for the entire day. [So basically OLHC] In my current serialization routine and builder I currently support an "all" property. Which is a method in the builder that sets all of the OHLC prices to one single price.

Is there a way to set this up without having to have the property name of all?

- On Serialization it should make the comparison and use all
- On deserialization it should redirect to the all method in the builder.

Is this possible in Jackson?

Example:

The data structure looks like:

```
EODPrice 

  - Open
  - Low
  - Close
  - High
```

Lets say we have the json: "`{all: 5.00}`" It would deserialize to Open: 5.00, low: 5.00, close: 5.00, and high: 5.00. If we were to serialize I would want to change the behavior so that if we have Open == Low == Close == High then we'd create one property called all. If that condition was not true, then we wouldn't serialize the "all" property at all.

Comment: I was just wondering if you could provide some more details. How do you expect the `all`-property to be serialized/deserialized. What is the comparison you mention?

Comment: I just changed the description to reflect it

Comment: I have added an answer that handles serialization. How do you expect the deserialization to work? What do you mean by *it should redirect to the all method in the builder*?

Comment: The all method is in the builder but not the built object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialization part is definitely possible by using the annotation `@JsonFilter` which you can read about in the [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter).

Deserialization is standard Jackson by the use of `@JsonCreator`.

Filters can be applied to classes, methods and fields and you can write your own custom filter that handles the open, low, close, high problem.

Check [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria) for an excellent introduction.

For a code sample, take a look at this. First, declare your `EODPrice` with the `@JsonFilter` annotation.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // required to skip the "all" attribute in the JSON
@JsonFilter("allFilter") // Specify the filter
public class EODPrice {
    private final BigDecimal close;
    private final BigDecimal high;
    private final BigDecimal low;
    private final BigDecimal open;

    // Builder method, does not include "all"
    @JsonCreator
    public EODPrice(
            @JsonProperty("open") final BigDecimal open,
            @JsonProperty("low") final BigDecimal low,
            @JsonProperty("close") final BigDecimal close,
            @JsonProperty("high") final BigDecimal high) {

        this.open = open;
        this.low = low;
        this.close = close;
        this.high = high;
    }

    // This is not part of the JSON but puts the business logic in the POJO
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean allFieldsEqual() {
        return open.equals(low) && open.equals(close) && open.equals(high);
    }

    public BigDecimal getAll() {
        if (allFieldsEqual()) {
            return open;
        }
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

    public BigDecimal getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public BigDecimal getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public BigDecimal getOpen() {
        return open;
    }
}
```

The filter can look something like this:

```
private PropertyFilter allFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(
            Object pojo,
            JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider,
            PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

        // If it is not the "all" property, go on with normal serialization
        if (!writer.getName().equals("all")) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            return;
        }

        // Else, check the special all-rule
        final EODPrice eodPrice = (EODPrice) pojo;
        if (eodPrice.allFieldsEqual()) {
            // Only serialize if all fields are equal
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Finally, setup the mapper. This testcase illustrates that the filter kicks in:

```
@Test
public void testJsonRoundtrip() throws IOException {
    final FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("allFilter", allFilter);
    final EODPrice eodPriceWithAll = new EODPrice(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);
    final EODPrice eodPriceWithoutAll = new EODPrice(BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setFilters(filters);

    // First, test serialization
    final String eodWithAllAsStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(eodPriceWithAll);
    final String eodWithoutAllAsStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(eodPriceWithoutAll);

    Assert.assertTrue(eodWithAllAsStr.contains("all"));
    Assert.assertFalse(eodWithoutAllAsStr.contains("all"));

    // Then, test deserialization
    final EODPrice eodPriceWithAll2 = mapper.readValue(eodWithAllAsStr, EODPrice.class);
    final EODPrice eodPriceWithoutAll2 = mapper.readValue(eodWithoutAllAsStr, EODPrice.class);

    Assert.assertTrue(eodPriceWithAll2.allFieldsEqual());
    Assert.assertFalse(eodPriceWithoutAll2.allFieldsEqual());
}
```

**EDIT:** After updates from the OP deserialization is added to the POJO. Furthermore, business logic is  moved from the filter to the POJO.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks. I'm going to have to read up on it and test it out before I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: The only concern about this is that: The all field does not exist in the immutable object. (Which would be done on serialization)

Comment: @monksy - After your input the answer has been updated. I have added the business logic for the *all* field to the immutable object. Furthermore, I have added code (and test code) for deserialization.

Comment: I can live with that. Thanks for your help! This was a great answer.